# Can I replace SDL_GetTicks with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock?

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl

Checking new stuff from C++, I have found the std::chrono library.

I am wondering if std::chrono::high_resolution_clock could be a good replacement for SDL_GetTicks?

Comment: I don't recommend it, std::chrono much slower...

Comment: Any follow up link or explanation on why `std::chrono` would be slower?

Comment: SDL_GetTicks is actually using the low 32 bits of SDL_GetTicks64, which on windows is using QueryPerformanceCounter().
std::chrono::steady_clock is implemented using QueryPerformanceCounter() as well. On MSVC, high_resolution_clock is the same as steady_clock.
So it's the same speed... You can use SDL_GetTicks64 or std::chrono, same thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The advantage of going with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is to keep away from storing time points and time durations in a `Uint32`.  The `std::chrono` library comes with a wide variety of `std::chrono::duration`s that you should use instead.  This will make code more readable, and less ambiguous:

```
Uint32 t0 = SDL_GetTicks();
// ...
Uint32 t1 = SDL_GetTicks();
// ...
// Is t1 a time point or time duration?
Uint32 d = t1 -t0;
// What units does d have?
```

vs:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
typedef high_resolution_clock Clock;
Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();
// ...
Clock::time_point t1 = Clock::now();
// ...
// Is t1 has type time_point.  It can't be mistaken for a time duration.
milliseconds d = t1 - t0;
// d has type milliseconds
```

The typed system for holding points in time and time durations has no overhead with respect to just storing things in a `Uint32`.  Except maybe that things will be stored in an `Int64` instead.  But even that you could customize if you really wanted to:

```
typedef duration<Uint32, milli> my_millisecond;
```

You can inspect the precision of the `high_resolution_clock` with:

```
cout << high_resolution_clock::period::num << '/' 
     << high_resolution_clock::period::den << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

SDL_GetTicks returns milliseconds so it is totally possible to use std::chrono instead, but mind the units conversion necessary. It may not be as simple as SDL_GetTicks. Also, the starting point won't be the same.

Comment: But I can simple create something like MyGetTicks to encapsulate the conversion. Is there any minimum precision requirement in the spec?

Comment: Not that I know. But there is some chances that std::chrono and SDL uses the same mechanisms, or at least a similar approach.